# Display changes with Git to zip's

Tags: git, msysgit

I'm using git-gui on Windows Vista (via msysgit), and I'm trying to make the diff area (the yellow one) display changes in office files (eg .xlsx - they are really zipped up .xml files)

In C:\Users\Daniel\

.gitconfig
`[diff "zip"]`
`textconv = unzip -c -a`

In repository: (As a side note, I'd rather have this in C:\Users\Daniel, **what should I do?**)

.gitattributes
`*.xlsx diff=zip`

After committing an .xlsx file, changing it and rescanning, I get this message:
`Binary files a/notes/GaussianMountain.xlsx and b/notes/GaussianMountain.xlsx differ`

Instead of an output listing the changes made! **What's wrong?**

Comment: Try running `git check-attr diff notes/GaussianMountain.xlsx`

Comment: Why do you need it? Usually MS applications alter the file structure greatly on every save (especially if different versions are used). So diffing may show lots of unnecessary (and messed up) information

Comment: I suspect this might be just due to your .gitconfig being in the wrong directory.  Alternatively, perhaps unzip can't be found and you're not seeing the error in the gui?  If you open up a git bash shell, change into the repository and try `git diff notes/GaussianMountain.xlsx` (or whatever you were doing before) - does that work?  If not, try setting the config option in the repository with: `git config diff.zip.textconv "unzip -c -a"`.  Also try `echo $HOME` there.  The other thing to check is that your .gitattributes file is in the git repository rather than in your home directory.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard, notes/GaussianMountain.xlsx: diff: zip

Comment: @Mark Longair, .gitconfig's in the correct directory, it has my other git config stuff.  Running git diff notes/GaussianMountain.xlsx, I get WARNING: terminal is not fully functional, but then pressing enter gives a vi style output of the diff (with + and -, etc).  It's in the repository

Comment: running "export TERM=msys" fixes diff, now it displays correctly and in colour

Comment: @Zeophlite: so that would be consistent with git-gui and the git bash shell looking in different places for .gitconfig, wouldn't it?  This thread http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/120d47b6111c17c0 suggests that if you set the environment variable HOME to C:\Users\Daniel\ that may force both to look in the same place, but perhaps that's out of date now.

Comment: @Mark Longair: typing env into a cmd prompt gives me HOMEDRIVE=C: , HOMEPATH=\Users\Daniel and USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Daniel . The file C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile has:
if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
  HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
  if [ -z "$HOME" -o ! -d "$HOME" ]; then
    HOME="$USERPROFILE"
  fi
fi
So I'm guessing that's not the problem?  Finally, I added the
[diff "zip"]
textconv = unzip -c -a
lines to C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update: it seems from the comments below that the problem for the questioner was needing a later version of git-gui / msysGit.  However, there are a couple of other problems I had while trying to reproduce the issue, which are described below.*

I think I managed to reproduce this: the problem seems to be that I had the checkbox "Use TextConv For Diffs and Blames" selected in Git Gui's `Edit > Options...` dialog.  When I turned *off* that option, it worked fine -- counterintuitively, to my mind, although that's also documented on the [TextConv page on the git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv).

The other problem I had was that the converter I was testing with (strings) wasn't on my path, so I had to put a full path in my .gitconfig:

```
[diff "stringify"]
    textconv = c:/cygwin/bin/strings.exe
```

However, if this had been the problem for you I don't think you would have seen the "Binary files A and B differ" message at all, so I suspect it's the former causing the problem.

Comment: Git gui doesn't have a "Use Textconv For Diffs and Blames" option in its Options dialog.  Git gui's `Help > About` dialog says my version is: git-gui version 0.12.GITGUI ; git version 1.7.0.2.msysgit.0 ; Here's a screen shot of it: http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/3376/gitgui.png

Comment: OK, I was using the latest version: git-gui version 0.13.GITGUI, git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0, and the options dialog definitely has the option in that version: http://mythic-beasts.com/~mark/git-gui-screenshot.png -- that said, there do seem to be bugs in this feature at the moment: when I started up git-gui again to take that screenshot I had to turn the option on and off again to get the text diffs to appear again :(  If you get it to work that far, that would be worth reporting...

Comment: Updating to msysgit 1.7.3.1 worked - the option "Use Textconv For Diffs and Blames" is checked, but its displaying properly.  Thanks for your help Mark

Comment: @Zeophlite: no problem - I've updated my answer to mention what your eventual solution was.