# IDE for eBooks to use version control

Tags: git, ide, epub

I want to write eBooks using Git as version control software. Since neither Git supports .epub files (at least not diff-able) nor Sigil or Calibre supports any kind of using an eBook as "project" (folder with containing files), I wanted to ask you how I could achieve this, if it's possible at all.
Since an .epub file is nothing more than a collection of folders and files, I don't see any problems with this, but I just can't find anything on Google...

**Edit**: Since I rather work with HTML and CSS files, I created my own solution for this problem: With [EpubCreator](https://github.com/CharlyDelta/EpubCreator) you are now able to place all your `.epub` files into the `src/` folder. As soon as you want to view your work up to now, you just can run the `index.php` script, which will in first instance assemble an `.epub` file from source and save it into the `bin/` folder. After that, it will call the just created `.epub` file and display it in your browser. It should then look like this:
[image]
There are now plugins or so needed, the displaying is achieved with epub.js, another project on GitHub (if you are interested, it is linked in the LICENSE.md in my project).
I hope this helps anybody. Also, as I often make ebooks, I will keep on with the work. This is now about 6 hours of work, I hope I will be able to improve it a lot. Thanks for your tips and inspiration.

Comment: What file format does your writing process use?

Comment: Good Q. VonC answer is probably the option. Similar quest on my part, I wanted to edit with a track-change environment. I almost set up MediaWiki with this extension http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EPubExport I would edit an "article" like it was a Chapter or Book. I never did try it.

Comment: Thanks four your replies. @mwu I don't understand your question. What do you mean with writing process? I am writing .html and .css files with Sigil, which immediately creates an .epub file if you save it.

Comment: @Paulb Well, that will export an .epub file, if I got you right? I'm not sure how this could help...

Comment: I had an idea reading your answers, thanks again! I updated my question and you will be informed as soon as I got it running like I wanted it ;)

Comment: I updated my question with another solution for the problem. Thanks everybody again

Comment: The links in the question and answer are no longer live, but this is likely a relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001663/can-git-treat-zip-files-as-directories-and-files-inside-the-zip-as-blobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to write your book in a text format (that Git can easily stored), and **generate** the target format from those sources.

The article "[Publishing eBooks with AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/publishing-ebooks-with-asciidoc.html)" illustrates that process, using [`asciidoc` format](http://asciidoc.org/) (text) to generate epub.
It uses the [`a2x`  toolchain manager](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/a2x.1.html) for the generation:

```
a2x -fepub -dbook minimal-book.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will take a look at it. If it helped, I will let you know, but it sounds good. I just need to find out if this also can be used with .html and .css files, since I'd rather use these languages instead of yet another markup language

Comment: I accepted this answer now, since it theoretically can perfectly solve the original problem posted, but for those who want to use HTML and CSS like me, I will update my question with another solution

Comment: for text to epub that looks fine.  What about graphics?

Comment: @Thufir 4 years later, I am not sure.

Comment: @Thufir Graphics are binary files. Git handles those just fine, but no granular diff.