# What is the best way to extract .zip file/folder structure then commit to Github using Github API?

Tags: github-api, unzip

I'm trying to place some config files under version control using Github. The ONLY way to get these particular config files is via a GET request to the hosting server. Server responds with a .zip file.

**.zip file structure looks similar to:**

```
|-Folder1
--|-File1.json
--|-File2.json
--|-Pic1.jpg
|-Folder2
--|-File3.json
--|Folder3
----|Pic2.jpg
|-File4.json
|-File5.json
```

As you can see, its a mix of text and binary files. Also has a nested folder structure.

**I need to:**

- Commit this .zip file to Github using the Github REST API (no problem there)
- But BEFORE committing, how can I programmatically extract the folders and files (LEAVING THE FOLDER STRUCTURE IN PLACE)
- Commit the results to Github

I've checked the question/solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001663/can-git-treat-zip-files-as-directories-and-files-inside-the-zip-as-blobs), but they don't quite match/are a few years old.

Anyone have a workflow for doing this? I have to imagine SOMEONE has come across similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Power Automate to handle this.

Basically,

- GET `.zip` file
- Add it to OneDrive for Business
- Extract it there (folder structure is "flattened", but luckily OneDrive "keeps" it by renaming each file)
- Example: `Folder1/File1.json` in the `.zip` becomes `Folder1_File1.json` once extracted
- When committing to Github via api, I just did a `replace` for the filename; INCLUDING the `/` as part of the path.
- Example URL: `https://api.github.com/repos/SeaDude/replace(items('FOR_EACH_app')?['properties']?['DisplayName'], ' ', '-')/contents/replace(items('FOR_EACH_source_file_2')?['Name'],'_','/')`

  - Apparently, you can specify an empty (or non-empty) path as part of an API commit. If the directory is empty, Github will create it!